# Mysql taking too long time to respond when using order by on alias

Tags: php, mysql, navicat

I am trying to sum two fields from two different table based on user id. Here is my query

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.`name`,
    users.`type`,
((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(answers.points),0) FROM answers WHERE answers.answered_by=users.id)
+
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points.point),0) FROM points WHERE points.user_id=users.id)) points 
FROM
    users
WHERE
    users.type = '3' GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

when I remove ORDER BY points  data is being fetched quickly. But with ORDER BY points It's taking too long time for almost 5 minutes. Sometimes connection lost message is returned.

Can someone please help? really struggling with this issue

as Progman asked here is the EXPLAIN of with ORDER BY

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY users   ALL PRIMARY             18396   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  points  ALL                 39  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  answers ALL                 240347  Using where
```

without ORDER BY

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY users   index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       100 Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  points  ALL                 39  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  answers ALL                 240347  Using where
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions. Also add the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` queries with and without your `ORDER BY points` part to your question as well.

Comment: Hi @Shabbir Ahmed please rewrite the query.. also use all query except order by clause inside subquery then use order by out side subquery ex SELECT * FROM (your query)t ORDER BY t.points; if you provide sample data then i can try it.

Comment: @Progman I edited the question. Can you please check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here subquery performs better for avoiding duplicacy

```
-- MySQL
SELECT u.id
     , u.name
     , u.type
     , COALESCE(p.points, 0) points
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.user_id, SUM(points) points
           FROM ( SELECT answered_by AS user_id, points
                  FROM answers

                  UNION ALL

                  SELECT user_id, point AS points
                  FROM points ) t
           GROUP BY t.user_id ) p
      ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.type = '3'
ORDER BY p.points DESC LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Comment: Hi @Shabbir Ahmed : Please check the above query and let me know if any questions regarding this.

Comment: OMG!!! bro thank you sooo much. You did a magic. It's a looot faster than before. You saved my day. I am grateful to you. btw Can you please explain why my approach isn't working as expected and this one is ? And why JOINING approach from another answer was returning garbage result ?

Comment: Thanks @ShabbirAhmed!! corelated subquery behaves slowly for a large dataset in compare with subquery and JOIN. In your query use 2 corelated subquery as aliases and also in order by clause. for single user both tables (answers and points) are executed 2 times. This is degraded performance. When you omit order by both tables executes one time and you get result but this is not suitable for large volume of data. JOINING approach is better but you'll get either garbage result or same value can be summed up multiple times when multiple record exists for a same user in answer or points table.

Comment: Thank you bro, for your explanation. It helped. Wish you great achievements.

Answer (score 0):

I can to advice next query:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.`name`,
    users.`type`,
    (
        IFNULL(SUM(answers.points),0) + 
        IFNULL(SUM(points.point),0)
    ) points 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.answered_by=users.id
LEFT JOIN points ON points.user_id=users.id
WHERE
    users.type = 3 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY points 
DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

Using JOIN should be more effective then sub-query

Comment: I tried this approach before this one. my points table may have negative values and multiple rows. points table may have user_id or not.. but answers table must have user_id which is answered_by here. When my points table have singe row against an user_id it gives me correct result, but when i have row with negative value it returns garbage result